# Why is heroku keeping multiple versions of compiled css and js?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, asset-pipeline

It looks like when I deploy to heroku, a few previous versions of my compiled assets are kept in the slug:

```
~/public/assets $ ls -larth application*
-rw------- 1 u37389 37389  11K 2013-11-15 18:23 application-19cb887ea38bdf0fd8646b21bf349be0.css.gz
-rw------- 1 u37389 37389  49K 2013-11-15 18:23 application-19cb887ea38bdf0fd8646b21bf349be0.css
-rw------- 1 u37389 37389  11K 2013-11-15 20:55 application-8ff01dce2de4e8a587ac42a6373e849b.css.gz
-rw------- 1 u37389 37389  49K 2013-11-15 20:55 application-8ff01dce2de4e8a587ac42a6373e849b.css
-rw------- 1 u37389 37389  57K 2013-11-15 21:22 application-8a4798f73479706126e89ce83063e6c6.js.gz
-rw------- 1 u37389 37389 163K 2013-11-15 21:22 application-8a4798f73479706126e89ce83063e6c6.js
-rw------- 1 u37389 37389  57K 2013-11-16 00:01 application-da815cda716669a04c5319163d8a33a9.js.gz
-rw------- 1 u37389 37389 163K 2013-11-16 00:01 application-da815cda716669a04c5319163d8a33a9.js
-rw------- 1 u37389 37389  57K 2013-11-16 18:38 application-2a3e3f64c150313847a6bf18fbc18650.js.gz
-rw------- 1 u37389 37389 161K 2013-11-16 18:38 application-2a3e3f64c150313847a6bf18fbc18650.js
-rw------- 1 u37389 37389  11K 2013-11-16 18:38 application-2677cfd470b2b5a8397c663aab03ece0.css.gz
-rw------- 1 u37389 37389  50K 2013-11-16 18:38 application-2677cfd470b2b5a8397c663aab03ece0.css
```

I can't replicate this behavior locally even if I run in production mode. So I'm assuming that this is a trick heroku does in order to allow previous versions of assets to stick around in case a client is still looking for it?

I've never heard of this and can't find any documentation about it -- what's going on here, and is it configurable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's tucked away, but was announced on [twitter](https://twitter.com/HerokuChangelog/status/382265700460421121):

Heroku keeps 50 MB of files in the tmp/cache/assets between deploys.

It can result in faster deploys (according to heroku)

https://devcenter.heroku.com/changelog-items/328?utm_source=dlvr.it&utm_medium=twitter